# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error

Tags: tables, errors

I am receiving the "extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error in producing a complicated table in LaTeX. The minimalist table below should replicate the error. I have read the other answers on StackExchange but they do not identify *why* this error arises. An answer will (a) identify the issue and a resolution and (b) why this is happening.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
    \caption{Test} 
        \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-3} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test} \\ 
 & Test & Test & Test \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: you define three cols with `lcc` but entered four on the `Test` entry row. Hence the `extra alignment tab`...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause of the error wasn't fully shown in the OP's example code and because the error was resolved based on information available only to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that I defined three columns with lcc but entered four on the Test entry row. This arose because the column names (excluded from the above code) had been "X & Y" which was converted from R's Stargazer to LaTeX literally and thus produced an extra column by accident.